# Save query results in one array

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I am absolute beginner with PHP. I am currently working on an Android App which has a webservice with PHP. I need to get the results of 2 executed SQL-Querys and convert it to json. My Problem is I do not get any result back to client, also I do not get any error. I think it is because I divided results into two arrays. How can I save the results of the 2 queries as one array, so as one json response?

Code EDITED:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost"; // host of MySQL server
    $user = "root"; // MySQL user
    $pwd = ""; // MySQL user's password
    $db = "food"; // database name

    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 
    //$uname = $_POST['uname'];

    // query the application data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE status = '0' ORDER By  precious_time DESC";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM uploads_avatar WHERE uname = 'sinii'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    // an array to save the application data
    $rows = array();
    $rows2 = array();

    // iterate to query result and add every rows into array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row; 

    }

    // iterate to query result and add every rows into array
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $rows2[] = $row2; 

    }

    $result_merge = array_merge($rows, $rows2);

    // close the database connection
    mysqli_close($con);


    // echo the application data in json format
    echo json_encode($result_merge);
    ?>
```

However I run the application without the second query with the second array etc., then it works, but I need the data of the second query too.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could merge your arrays using [array_merge](http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: What are the results of the queries when executed directly against the database? Do they even retrieve result sets? If there are no records found, your arrays will stay empty.

Comment: Try doing it like: $sql $result $rows while()..second query $sql2 $result2 $rows2 while()....in my experience this works the best.

Comment: Please see my edited code. I am now using array_merge but when I test it on browser I only get the results from first query :-(

Answer (score 1):

For getting value in one array use array_merge to merge both the arrays or you could do it i n this format

```
$jsonResult = array();

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $jsonResult["uploads"][] = $row; 
}


while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $jsonResult["upload_avatar"][] = $row2; 
}

echo json_encode($jsonResult);
```

Using array merge

```
 $jsonResult = array_merge($rows, $rows2);
   echo json_encode($jsonResult);
```

As for json response you should first check the response by seeing the response in a web browser first.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but in your example there is just one array named `$jsonResult`. So there is nothing to merge, or?

Comment: Please see my edited code. I am now using merge but I only get shown the results from first query in browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Can u check just the response of your second array($rows2) whether it is empty or not.Do a print_r($rows2) ?

Comment: ok I got it work on serverside...now I have to catch the merged array on java-side with json. Do you also have a best practice for this :-)

Comment: Personally there is no hard and fast rule as in such.The response which you would be getting would be jsonarray whereas in my workflow i try to send the response from server to app in a json object format

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use a MySQL query to merge the two tables when querying??

select * from uploads,uploads_avatar where uploads.status = '0' and uploads_avatar.uname = 'sinii';

Comment: Ok I'll give a try with your suggestion.

Comment: This will result in incorrect output if there is no matching value in database.For example it will generate an empty set when there is content in  uploads but not in upload_avatar